# SOAP requests to CRM2011 via PHP

Tags: php, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a lead in the Microsoft Dynamic 2011. I have connected my PHP script to the CRM and I get positive feedback.

I have used Fiddler to get a soap code that was used to create a lead in the CRM2011. However, when I use same code through my PHP script I get 'false' return.

The soap code that I have discovered is below:

```
   <s:Body>
        <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2009/WebServices">
                <command>1</command>
                <commandXml>
                    <Input>
                        <id>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</id>
                        <name>lead</name>
                        <formId>e3b6ddb7-8df0-4410-ac7b-fd32e5053d38</formId>
                        <dataxml>
                            <lead>
                                <leadqualitycode>2</leadqualitycode>
                                <statuscode>1</statuscode>
                                <ownerid type="8" name="Vlad Hercules">{6710C3A0-6EE9-E211-B17C-984BE16D3DAA}</ownerid>
                                <decisionmaker>0</decisionmaker>
                                <salesstage>0</salesstage>
                                <subject>subject</subject>
                                <lastname>vladislav</lastname>
                                <transactioncurrencyid type="9105" name="usd">{5B1C0B98-6CE9-E211-8B44-984BE17C9A7B}</transactioncurrencyid>
                                <preferredcontactmethodcode>1</preferredcontactmethodcode>
                                <donotemail>0</donotemail>
                                <donotbulkemail>0</donotbulkemail>
                                <donotphone>0</donotphone>
                                <donotpostalmail>0</donotpostalmail>
                                <donotsendmm>0</donotsendmm>
                            </lead>
                        </dataxml>
                        <associations></associations>
                    </Input>
                </commandXml>
            </Execute>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

How can this issue be resolved? Where can i get information on how requests look?

The example which was provided by microsoft returns false when I tried it:

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
                    <entity xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <b:Attributes xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                <c:key>name</c:key>
                                <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Newer Corporation</c:value>
                            </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        </b:Attributes>
                        <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                        <b:FormattedValues xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                        <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                        <b:LogicalName>account</b:LogicalName>
                        <b:RelatedEntities xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    </entity>
                    </Create>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly an expert on CRM2011 SOAP calls so I haven't seen that type of query before however i would suggest you try using something similar to the following.

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
      <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>leadqualitycode</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
               <a:Value>2</a:Value>
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>statuscode</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
               <a:Value>1</a:Value>
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>ownerid</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
               <a:Id>{6710C3A0-6EE9-E211-B17C-984BE16D3DAA}</a:Id>
               <a:LogicalName>systemuser</a:LogicalName>
               <a:Name i:nil="true" />
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>decisionmaker</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>salesstage</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
               <a:Value>0</a:Value>
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>subject</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:string">subject</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>lastname</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:string">vladislav</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>transactioncurrencyid</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
               <a:Id>{5B1C0B98-6CE9-E211-8B44-984BE17C9A7B}</a:Id>
               <a:LogicalName>transactioncurrency</a:LogicalName>
               <a:Name i:nil="true" />
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>preferredcontactmethodcode</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
               <a:Value>1</a:Value>
            </b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>donotemail</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>donotbulkemail</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>donotphone</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>donotpostalmail</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
         <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>donotsendmm</b:key>
            <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:boolean">0</b:value>
         </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      </a:Attributes>
      <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
      <a:FormattedValues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
      <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
      <a:LogicalName>lead</a:LogicalName>
      <a:RelatedEntities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
   </entity>
</Create>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work. However, how did you come up with this solution?

Comment: @user1652382 This code works. I tested it before putting it up.  
There is a few examples out there that I have found useful. When you say it returns "false" how are you getting this result? You should be able to read the SOAP response which should tell you if it was successful or not.  
I have started documenting some SOAP-CRM stuff here  
http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-using.html    

What method are you using to call your SOAP?    

Also what Authentication type?

Comment: @user1652382 have you had success with the above request now?

Comment: At the end the issue was with the access. The code that you gave does work.