# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013: ADD via SOAP/PHP - XML structure issue

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Microsoft Dynamics CRM is driving me nuts these days (and sadly I'm completely new to this stuff).  I'm trying to add via PHP/SOAP a new record to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Account entity but I keep getting no answers. According to [Campey's blog](http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.it/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-calls.html) an ADD xml request Body should contain "create" tag like this

```
<create xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
    <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
      <a:attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
  <!-- ATTRIBUTE XML GOES HERE!! -->
      </a:attributes>
      <a:entitystate i:nil="true">
      <a:formattedvalues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <a:id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:id>
      <a:logicalname><!-- ENTITY NAME GOES HERE!! --></a:logicalname>
      <a:relatedentities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    </a:relatedentities></a:formattedvalues></a:entitystate></entity>
</create>
```

I already have a working script downloading items list using "request" tag so I am sure that "Header" part is fully working and I can concentrate on "s:Body". 
I put Campey's example snippet inside "Execute->request" tag, as follows. BUT this causes me errors. **Seems is connected to request tag xmlns attribute but not sure about that**. Thanx in advance for your precious help!

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. 

The InnerException message was 'Error in line 2 position 38. 

Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing:CreateRequest'. 

The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'CreateRequest' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'.'. Please see InnerException for more detail
```

XML structure

```
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <request i:type="a:CreateRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">

            <create xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">

            <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
      <a:attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
 <a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                                <b:key>name</b:key>
                                <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">aaa-test</b:value>
                            </a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
      </a:attributes>
      <a:entitystate i:nil="true">
      <a:formattedvalues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <a:id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:id>
      <a:logicalname>account</a:logicalname>
      <a:relatedentities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    </a:relatedentities></a:formattedvalues></a:entitystate></entity>
</create>
    </request>
        </Execute>
```

**[SOLUTION] UPDATE AFTER HOURS OF WTFing**
I still don't know why but I had to remove "create" tag and use just execute->request. Once I placed a "request" tag with CreateRequest type it worked. That's the code in case someone else needs it. Not sure if there had been a change of the XML structure from CRM 2011 to CRM 2013 or it was just badly documented. By the way, thanx a lot for your help!

```
<Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
      <request i:type='a:CreateRequest' xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'>
        <a:Parameters xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic'>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>Target</b:key>
            <b:value i:type='a:Entity'>
              <a:Attributes>
                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>name</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>test1234</b:value>
                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              </a:Attributes>
              <a:EntityState i:nil='true' />
              <a:FormattedValues />
              <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>account</a:LogicalName>
              <a:RelatedEntities />
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil='true' />
        <a:RequestName>Create</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
```

Comment: Maybe this question on StackOverflow helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777810/soap-requests-to-crm2011-via-php

Comment: Thanx Henk but same issue, I checked right that question to see if my KeyValuePairOfstringanyType tag was ok before posting but it gave me no clue about the entire xml structure. Anyway I found a solution right now.

Comment: That's odd. What endpoint are you exactly targeting, organization.svc, organization.svc/web?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're close!

Remove the 
Execute and request lines

You should only need the `<create>` area
So your whole request should look like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            HEADER GOES HERE
            <s:Body>
                <create xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">

            <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
      <a:attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
 <a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
                                <b:key>name</b:key>
                                <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">aaa-test</b:value>
                            </a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
      </a:attributes>
      <a:entitystate i:nil="true">
      <a:formattedvalues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <a:id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:id>
      <a:logicalname>account</a:logicalname>
      <a:relatedentities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    </a:relatedentities></a:formattedvalues></a:entitystate></entity>
</create>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sadly if I try to use that structure I get an even more generic error: "InternalServiceFaultThe server was unable to process the request due to an internal error."

Comment: Finally I solved that, thanx you for your help anyway. Sounds odd but I had to use request param (with CreateRequest type) instead of create. This makes no sense if I read guidelines. There probably had been a change in XML structure from 2011 to 2013, dunno. I'll update my first post in case someone else has the same issue.